# Raspberry Pi Camera feedback freezes when moving NEMA 17 stepper motor with A4988 stepper motor driver

Tags: raspbian, camera, power-supply, ffmpeg

I have a Raspberry Pi with a camera module and a NEMA 17 stepper motor connected to it. When I run the command ffplay /dev/video0, the video runs perfectly. However, whilst the video is running, and I run a script that moves the Stepper motor with the A4988 stepper motor driver, the video feed freezes and needs to be restarted.

At first I thought it was ffmpeg's fault, so I tried viewing the feed with OpenCV, but the same probelem persisted.

I also thought that the CPU prioritization was causing the problem, but this one time, the entire Raspberry Pi froze. The Keyboard, mouse, keys, numlock key, everything was dead (the Numlock light on my keyboard was on, I tried toggling the NumLock, but it did not go off) and so I had to turn off and turn on again the power supply to reboot the Pi.

How do I get rid of this issue?

Comment: I doubt this is specific to the Pi.  You need to track down the problem.  Most likely insufficient power supply or electrical noise.

Comment: How is it wired electrically?

Comment: The A4988 driver was placed on top of an expansion board where the VMOT was powered by an AC adaptor, and the Pi was powered with the adaptor that comes with the kit (with the logo and all). Could the expansion board be the culprit?